# Force re-compute to Vue computed property?

Tags: vuejs2

Is it possible to re-compute a computed property in vue? I have a simple line item total (price x quantity). If the box is checked and an input value changed, the property re-computes. If I uncheck the box, the computed property remains. My desired behavior is to reset the value shown to be 0. I was thinking adding a hidden value that on checkbox toggle is set to 1 or 0, then adding that to the multiplication - i.e. this.line_units * this.line_rate * this.is_toggled, but it seems a bit hacky. Anyone have a better way to do this?

```
<template>
<tr :class="{ 'row-disabled': !enabled }">
    <td><input type="checkbox" @change="toggle" :value="checkbox" class="form-check-input" :checked="enabled"></td>
    <td>{{ description }}</td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" @change="setLineUnits" :value="line_units" class="form-control" :disabled="!enabled"></td>
    <td><input type="number" min="0" @change="setLineRate" :value="line_rate" class="form-control" :disabled="!enabled"></td>
    <td>${{ total.toFixed(2) }}</td>
</tr>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.row-disabled {
background: #ddd;
color: #555;
}
</style>
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {

    };
},
computed: {
    total: {
        cache: false,
        get: function() {
            if (this.enabled) {
                return this.line_units * this.line_rate;
            } else return 0;
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    toggle() {
        this.$emit('lineInput', {
            enabled: !this.enabled
        })
    },
    setLineUnits(evt) {
        this.$emit('lineInput', {
            line_units: Number(evt.target.value)
        })
    },
    setLineRate(evt) {
        this.$emit('lineInput', {
            line_rate: Number(evt.target.value)
        })
    }
},
props: {
    enabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    line_rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    line_units: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: try to use `v-model` instead `:value`.

Answer (score -1):

You're not changing any values, so the @changed event isn't firing. `enabled` isn't bound to the input, and the `:changed/:value` properties are only bound one way.

I'd suggest using @click, unless you have some other reason for preferring not to.